# Маршруты вида /api/users/:id/cars/:id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Как правильно реализовать маршруты вида /api/users/:id/cars/:id.

Допустим имеем модели `User` и `Car` (с отношением один ко многим):

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Имеем контроллер UsersController:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(user);
    }
    //тут все остальные методы
}
```

Имеем контроллер CarsController:

```
public class CarsController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(Car))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCar(int id)
    {
        Car car = db.Cars.Find(id);
        if (car == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(car);
    }
    //тут все остальные методы
}
```

Для получения конкретного пользователя обращаемся по маршруту /Users/:id.

Для получения конкретной машины обращаемся по маршруту /Cars/:id

Как получить машины конкретного пользователя? Добавить дополнительный метод в контроллер пользователя или как?

Comment: да, можно добавить дополнительный метод в контроллер пользователя

Comment: Добавить дополнительный метод в `CarsController` было бы более логично...

Comment: @Grundy, это является best practice?))

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а почему в CarsController было бы логичнее? мы же обращаемся к машине конкретного пользователя

Comment: мы же обращаемся **к машине**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, добавлять такой маршрут надо в тот контроллер, где его будет удобнее реализовать.

Ничто не мешает ни складывать все маршруты в один контроллер - ни растаскивать их по разным. Но у контроллеров могут быть свои зависимости - и имеет смысл группировать действия так, чтобы этих зависимостей было меньше.

В вашем случае все три действия (пока что) зависят только от базы данных - поэтому правильный способ их размещения по контроллерам - вопрос холиварный. Как только контроллеры перестанут быть столь тривиальными - их зависимости помогут сгруппировать действия наиболее красивым образом.

А чтобы было проще "перетаскивать" действия из одного контроллера в другой - рекомендую воспользоваться [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2):

```
[Route("api/users/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id) { ... }

[Route("api/cars/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Car))]
public IHttpActionResult GetCar(int id) { ... }

[Route("api/users/{userid}/cars/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Car))]
public IHttpActionResult GetCar(int id, int userid) { ... }
```

Comment: про Attribute Routing в курсе, просто хотелось узнать как делают другие. Большое спасибо за ответ.